# COUNTIF dependend on cell format and input type?

Tags: excel, floating-point, countif

Question: Is the `COUNTIF` function working inconsistent with different data types and cell formats?

The situation:

[image: manual input]

Column A contains manually created numbers (to be used in SAP). The numbers are 18 characters long, don't contain any non digit chars. The cell format has to be `Text` as we would face more issues down the line if it wouldn't. If I apply the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A;A2)` the result is as shown in column C. However this obviously not the correct result.

Another example with "real" test data from a system extract:
[image: system extract]

The issue here is, that the `COUNTIF` function sometimes returns the correct result, sometimes a wrong result. I cannot figure out why its working the way it does.
Also I did not find any satisfying result somewhere else on the Internet. If I missed something, please let me know.

As a side note: If I transfer the data into a `PIVOT` table it always shows the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Problem:***

This will most likely be due to floating point errors.

Excel's `COUNTIF` function will try to handle these values in `A` column as numbers. Because Excel uses IEEE 754 specification on how to store and calculate floating-point numbers, Excel therefore stores only 15 significant digits in a number, and changes trailing digits after the fifteenth place to zeroes. [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells).

---

***For example:***

`541235479876536549` will become `541235479876536000`

`541235479876536550` will become `541235479876536000`

`541235479876536551` will become `541235479876536000`

`541235479876536552` will become `541235479876536000`

That would mean your values are 3 digits too long to be handled accurately. In this example, the unique values will all be counted 4 times using `COUNTIF`. 
Removing the last three digits from your string should therefor make the `COUNTIF` behave as expected. However, this will still give you unwanted results as you don't want to mess with the original data.

---

***Solution:***

If using a pivot table (which probably works as it should pick up the data as text) is not what you want, maybe you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$11=A2))
```

> ***Note:*** On a large dataset, array-formulas might slow down your
>   workbook significantly!

Furthermore, `COUNTIF` is not the only function that would suffer from this behaviour. The scope of this problem included functions like `SUMIF`, `SUMIFS`, `COUNTIF`, `COUNTIFS`, `AVERAGEIF`, and `AVERAGEIFS`. [Source](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-long-numbers-without-countif)

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the resource! 
I'm working with pivot table as the data sets are quite large (100.000+ lines).